# update column data using access sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to update column data,i.e if column data contains '2u' or '3u' at end and replace with 'ui'. How do i achive this using the access sql query

sample table

```
       col1     col2

       562u    yu3u
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to provide a bit more information but if I get what you're after you could use a SQL command like this:

```
UPDATE <tablename>
SET col1 = MID(col1, 1, LEN(col1) - 2) & 'ui'
WHERE col1 LIKE '*2u' or col1 LIKE '*3u'
```

You'll need to run the query for the second column separately:

```
UPDATE <tablename>
SET col2 = MID(col2, 1, LEN(col2) - 2) & 'ui'
WHERE col2 LIKE '*2u' or col2 LIKE '*3u'
```

Comment: thank you. but i need to remove last two characters i.e '2u' and '3u' and place 'ui' and column data should be like '56ui , yuui